# How to fix cloth getting sucked inside mesh?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

So I was trying to make a sort of carpet on the surface of stairs. I ran the simulation but the cloth gets sucked inside the collision mesh.

[image: Cloth glitch 2] [image: Cloth glitch 1]

I made sure there are no holes in the geometry, increased the amount of geometry but nothing seems to work. What could be done about it ?

Blend file :
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Alright i uploaded

Comment: it seems to work fine, what Blender version do you use? https://zupimages.net/up/22/44/43st.jpg maybe apply the scale of the floor?